# Share logged user object with service but data is lost between component

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have created an injectable UserService class to store an object (the logged user).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {


  private _loggedUser : User;

  setLoggedUser(loggedUser: User) 
  {
    this._loggedUser = loggedUser;
  }

  getLoggedUser(): User
  {
      console.log("getLoggedUser login = " + this._loggedUser.login); // ERROR HERE
      return this._loggedUser;
  }

}
```

On my login component I have :

```
this.userService.setLoggedUser(loggedUser);
```

And on another component I want to get my loggedUser object via :

```
this.userService.getLoggedUser();
```

But I got

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login')

So I guess the object is not store. Any idea why ?

What I want to do is actually quite common, store current user context.

I know about sessionStorage.getItem('id');  but I head it is not secure.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Use BehaviorSubject for data persistent and available to all classes importing the service.

Comment: You are right. But I have an issue using the BehaviorSubject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135806/value-of-behaviorsubject-in-service-to-share-data-between-component-is-not-upd

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at using rxjs and moving the data between the components via subject or behavior subject.  this is call micro services - where you bind data from one service and share and set it from unrelated components.

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject

Comment: You are right. But I have an issue using the BehaviorSubject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135806/value-of-behaviorsubject-in-service-to-share-data-between-component-is-not-upd