# Value of BehaviorSubject in Service (to share data between component) is not updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I'm trying to use a service with `BehaviorSubject` to share data between my root component and a component.

Here is the service :

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {  
    public loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<string>("INITIAL");
    castUser = this.loggedUser.asObservable();
       
    editUser(newLoggedUser : string){
        this.loggedUser.next(newLoggedUser);
    }
}
```

On my `RootComponent` I have :

```
this.userService.editUser("HELLO");
```

And on my other component I have (I put this code in the `ngOnInit` function or in `ngAfterViewInit` but it is the same) :

```
constructor(private userService : UserService) {
    this.userService.castUser.subscribe(userFirstname => {
        console.log("UserProfileComponent constructor userFirstname = " + userFirstname); // always displays "INITIAL"
    });
}
```

The problem is that when the subscribed function is called, it should display `HELLO`, and not `INITIAL`. It does not display the new value.

Any idea?

Comment: I simulated this issue on the StackBlitz and did not see any unusual behavior. Can you reproduce this problem?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zdhau?file=src%2Ftester.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fother.component.ts

Comment: You call editUser("HELLO") on main, then the first value when you subscribe is Hello not initial, call editUser("HELLO") after your subscribe

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili I see. Is it possible that it does not work for me because the Component2 is displayed in my RootCompoment template with <router-outlet></router-outlet> instead of a selector ? Is it possible that the constructor of my Component2 is called BEFORE the constructor of the RootComponent ?

Comment: hmm anyway it is an obervable, so even if the constructor of my Component2 is called before the constructor of my RootComponent it still should work.

Answer (score 1):

I fount it ! It was because I add

providers: [UserService]

in my component decorator.

I don't know why, because of that, there were different instance of UserService

Thank  Mojtaba Nejad Poor Esmaeili for the time you spent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the editUser call from your main or you change the last value of your BehaviourSubject, then you subscribe to your Observable and then call the editUser.

Then you have 2 value in console "INITIAL" then "HELLO"

```
export class OtherComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private testerService: TesterService) {
    this.testerService.castUser.subscribe((userFirstname) => {
      console.log(
        'UserProfileComponent constructor userFirstname = ' + userFirstname
      );
    });

    this.testerService.editUser('HELLO');
  }
}
```

then main

```
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: My root component is the component who update the data (as it it the the component which handle the login process). So the this.testerService.editUser has to be in this component. If the component who update the value is the same component that read the value, I don't need to use a service or an observable.